# Order of integration of triple integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Having a bit of trouble solving this problem. The problem goes:

Find $f(x,t)$ that satisfies : $$\int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z 2e^{t^3} \, dt \, dz \, dy = \int_0^x f(x,t)e^{t^3} \, dt$$ 
I know that I have to change the order of integration, but the region seems a bit too complicated to calculate.

It seems that the question intentionally changed $x$ to $t$ to complicate the problem (so, $x$ here would be scalar).

Would appreciate any tips/advice on the bounds of the integral.

Comment: Are you sure of the integral on the LHS?

Comment: Your integration variables shouldn't also be limits. Perhaps you should prime some variables.

Comment: /gimnusi: Yup, double checked it and that's what the question said

Comment: /J.G. : Not clear on what you mean by "prime" some variables, could you please specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^x \left( \int_0^y\left(\int_0^z 2e^{t^3} \, dt\right) \, dz\right) \, dy \\[10pt]
= {} & \iiint\limits_{\{\,(x,y,z)\,:\, 0\,\le\, t\,\le\, z\,\le\, y\,\le\,x \,\}} 2e^{t^3} \, d(t,z,y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x \left( \int_t^x \left( \int_z^x 2e^{t^3} \, dy \right) \,dz \right) \, dt \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x \left( \int_t^x \left( (x-z)2e^{t^3} \right) \, dz \right) \,dt \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x \left[ \left( xz - \frac {z^2} 2 \right) 2e^{t^3} \right]_{z\,:=\,t}^{z\,:=\,x}  \, dt \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^x \left( \left( \frac{x^2} 2 - \left(xt - \frac{t^2} 2\right) \right) 2e^{t^3} \right) \, dt
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution!

Comment: @Courier12 : I'm glad it helps.